# li:after in horizontal navigation bar keeps putting its content on a new line

Tags: html, css

I have some silly CSS problem. Cant get my navi bar working the way I would want it.
Problem is, that it keeps the arrows under anchor text somehow.

This is example of html:

```
<ul id="navi">
    <li><a href="">abc</a></li>
    <li><a href="">def</a></li>
    <li><a href="">ghi</a></li>
</ul>
```

and stylesheet:

```
#navi {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
#navi li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#navi li a {
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #222;
    padding: 0.2em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navi li a:hover, #navi li a:active {
    background: #5ea0ff;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navi li a.selected {
    background: #444;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#navi li:after {
    content: "\25B6";
}
#navi li:last-of-type:after {
    content: "";
}
```

This is how it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/M2AHY/1/

I want the arrows right after anchors, but I can't use a:after (which works good, but hovers with anchor text)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the element the arrow is appearing after, the anchor tag, is styled with `display:block` - a property which by itself, will push subsequent content to a new line. If altering this slightly won't be a problem, you could replace the style with:

```
#navi li a {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Which allows the arrow to appear on the same line. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M2AHY/4/) to demonstrate. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

**EDIT:** Alternatively, you may apply a float to the anchor tag. For example:

```
#navi li a {
    float:left;
}
```

This lets you retain the block display, but also allows the arrow to appear on the same line.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I wanted. Simple and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach to resolving this would be:

```
#navi li a:after {
    content: " \25B6";
}
```

Note that I've added the content after the  and put a space in the content.  Hope that helps!

Comment: The approach I would have taken, except at the end of the question he noted "I want the arrows right after anchors, but I can't use a:after (which works good, but hovers with anchor text)".

Comment: I missed that.. Your approach of floating the <a> left would be my next approach.